# How to use Runtime Light Bake in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to create runtime light baking in Unity for indoor interior. Is there any way to do this?

I want to do runtime light baking in Unity. It's possible to bake lights in the editor, but I am looking for a way to do it at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RealAPI](https://realistic3.com) for that. Can **render** or **bake** at runtime.

- [API Docs](https://docs.realistic3.com)
- [Official website](https://realistic3.com)
- [Demo website](https://3d.real-api.com)

Also:

[Demo video](https://youtu.be/CNMQs3KwsaA?si=aUeQ4Y7RaciSyJew)

[Demo video 2](https://youtu.be/wIcT9Fw0OcE?si=8VQ10Fb3-D2F0OUw)